How to delete most data from a 2,000GB Mysql InnoDB table
I have a Mysql InnoDB table with storage size(+index) over 2,000GB, There are 14 billion rows in that table..
I need to drop data added over 1 month ago, and figure out a way to always keep recent 1 month data in that table.
For data deletion, what I know is I cannot just do below as it generates huge amount of undo logs:
delete * from where eventtime < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
What I figured is to create a new table with same structure to the original table, and then create INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE triggers on the original table to sync all the writes to the new table, let it be there for 1 month, and then:
RENAME TABLE myOriginalTableName TO Old, New TO myOriginalTableName; 

Then
DROP TABLE Old;

As for always keeping recent 1 month data in the table, I'm planning to have a daily cronjob to delete data older than 1 month, and have a weekly cronjob to OPTIMIZE TABLE to reclaim the freed space after deletes.
Any issues with this plan? Any suggestions if it would not work?

If this is something you expect to do on a regular basis, you should use a partitioned table. Then you can just drop whole partitions.

You can partition by month, and then drop all but the current month.

Remove it in batches, start with for example 500 days ago. Then 450 days ago, etc. Or do it day by day, whatever works for you.

I would delete 50,000 rows at a time in 10 minute intervals.  We did this in my production replicated environments to reduce the number of rows "slowly".  DELETE FROM A         WHERE Created < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH         LIMIT 50000;
Then run this in a CRON job every 10 minutes.  This is more of "maintenance" planning event than a one-time big-bang.  Set this up, and let it run, you'll catch-up the deletes and you'll never need to touch it again.

Copy the data you want to keep to a new table; drop the old table; rename the copy to the old table’s name. Use the partitioning strategy going forward

The latest version of pt-online-schema-change 3.6.0 has an option to do exactly what you described. Read https://www.percona.com/blog/partial-data-archiving-and-schema-change/ for the announcement and instructions.

See https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig for various efficient ways to do big deletes.

@BillKarwin Thank you, this is what I'm looking for.

you can use mysql event scheduler to trigger this process ( delete and optimize ) every day
Create event delete_optimize
on schedule every 1 day 
do 
begin
  delete from myOriginalTableName where eventtime < current_date() - INTERVAL 30 day;
  Optimize table myOriginalTableName;
end


You can limit the numbers of your delete, so you have smaller transactions, which execute very fast.
DELTE * FROM tablename WHERE eventtime < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY LIMIT 10000;

Just schedule this from your application e.g. by a cron-job to run infinite or until no more rows are deleted.
